# get permanent facebook access token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have used JSDK to authenticate user for my facebook app. 
I am getting the access token but it gets expired within 1/2 hours. 
So how can I get long term Access Token?

The code I have used is:

```
 var fb = new FacebookClient();
 Dictionary<string,Object> sParams=new Dictionary<string,Object>();
 sParams.Add("client_id",My_App_ID);
 sParams.Add("client_secret",My_App_Secret);
 sParams.Add("grant_type","fb_exchange_token");
 sParams.Add("fb_exchange_token",Short_lived_accessToken);
 dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token",sParams);
 fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```

but it gives me error **Invalid JSON String** at line `dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token",sParams);`

What wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
        var client = new FacebookClient(Short_lived_accessToken);

        dynamic result = client.Post("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = My_App_ID,
            client_secret = My_App_Secret,
            grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
            fb_exchange_token = Short_lived_accessToken
        });

        Response.Write("Long live access token: [" + result.access_token + "]");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The return you will get from the endpoint simply *is not* JSON, but just plain text in the form

```
access_token=new_long-lived_access_token&expires=5130106
```

So you will have to tell your application somehow(?), that the result is not JSON; or you might have to use a different method altogether to make the request, if FacebookClient::Get always expects the answer to be JSON.

Comment: yes,thats why i have used dynamic datatype here to fetch result of FacebookClient.Get(), but it is not working.

Comment: Then it’s probably FacebookClient.Get() itself that throws the error, because it wants JSON and nothing else. Look for another method to make an HTTP request and get the response, without this requirement.

Comment: FacebookClient.Get() parsing for /oauth requests is only supported in v6. for v5 use FacebookOAuthClient. more info at  http://csharpsdk.org/docs/faq